# Gails criteria query to get cartesian product and return results as list of object arrays

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have 2 domain classes that look like this:

```
class Organisation {
    String name

    static hasMany = [users: User]
}

class User {
    String emailAddress

    static belongsTo = [organisation: Organisation]
}
```

I want to create a criteria query that returns the cartesian product of these.

My criteria closure looks like this:

```
    def criteriaClosure = {
        and {
            createAlias('users', 'u', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

            eq('someProperty', 'someValue')
            //...
        }
    }
```

This works, in the sense that the results list contains an `Organisation` for every element in the `users` collection, but I'd actually like the results to be a list of `Object[]`s like this:

```
Organisation1 | User1
Organisation1 | User2
Organisation1 | User3
Organisation2 | null
Organisation3 | User4
```

So, in the above example `Organisation1` has 3 `User`s in its `users` collection, `Organisation2` has none, and `Organisation3` has 1 `User`.

I know I can achieve this using HQL by `select`ing multiple items (e.g. `select organisation, user from...`) but is there some way to do this with a criteria query?

EDIT:

I've tried to apply a projection by adding this block:

```
projections {
    property "users"
}
```

however, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (maybe I can't express a projection like this against a collection?)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to use `projections`:

```
    def criteriaClosure = {
        projections{
          property 'name'
          property 'emailAddress' // maybe 'user.emailAddress'
        }
        and {
            createAlias('users', 'u', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

            eq('someProperty', 'someValue')
            //...
        }
    }
```

see [ref-doc](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

Comment: I was thinking using a projection might be the way to go - however I don't have a property called `organisation` or `user` - `users` is a collection, and the organisation is the class I'm querying against (and doesn't itself have an `organisation` property).

Comment: I put it only as an example. you should use the properties you want to return

Comment: I've updated my question to show what my domain classes look like. How can I express that I want to choose both the `Organisation` and `User` in the projections block?

Comment: Ahh, it turns out if you add `resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)`, the resutlset returned is broken down into a list of maps that contains 2 elements: one labelled 'this' (for the organisation) and one labelled 'u' (for the user)